# xamarin navigation bar not showing TitleView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

New to Xamarin and I'm trying to create a custom navigation bar in my Cross-Platform App. After some reading I found that I might be able to use the the title-view  component in my xaml page file like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="amici.MyGroups">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Left"/>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Center"/>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Right"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid x:Name="grid1">
                <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Welcome"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                   <ActivityIndicator x:Name="WaitIcon"  IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I navigate to my page "MyGroups" like this :  Navigation.PushAsync(new MyGroups());.

However, the only thing that shows is the default navigation page with the back icon arrow?

obliviously I missing something, or I don't understand something. Does this need to be done at the application level?

Comment: You can set a custom `TitleView` for a `NavigationPage` change the navigation event to `Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyGroups()));`, can you see your custom title view now?

Comment: @Evz sorry but know just the default bar with the default back arrow.

Comment: What is the targeting platform?

Comment: @Evz Yes now (I change the call in the wrong spot ) But now I have two navigation bars one with arrow and one with my Title View. and if I set the NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" then I just get the default one and the title view don't show. I need to do some more reading on this because I don't seem to understand whats going on LOL.

Comment: I will try to guide you on that by converting my comment to a proper answer.

Comment: @Mike If its your master detail page then just use  App.Current.MainPage = new MyGroups(); , this way you can't have two navigation bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As XAML states:
`<NavigationPage.TitleView> .. </NavigationPage.TitleView>`

You could set a totally custom `View` as a `NavigationBar`, however, this is possible only on `NavigationPage`s. Your code is partly correct because you set the `NavigationPage.TitleView` not on a `NavigationPage`:
`Navigation.PushAsync(new MyGroups())`

If you will navigate to a `NavigationPage`:
`Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyGroups()))`

You should see your custom `NavigationPage.TitleView`. The outcome, however, will depend on your current navigation model and you may end up with multiple navigation bars. That is because you will nest a `NavigationPage` within another `NavigationPage`.

I would strongly recommend reading the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical) on this topic so it would become clear for you.

Comment: Yes, I need  more of understanding what I'm doing. Thank you.

Comment: Jut a note, I went back and read the docs and I have my page setup just like it says. however, if I follow instruction TitleView still does not show unless I do Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyGroups())) which shows the double nav bar. so I'm lost..

Comment: @Mike can you please tel me ,if you have resolved the above issue. even i'm facing same

Comment: @Divya I had to set my navigation like this await Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewLikes());

Comment: @Mike Yeah even i have set my navigation similar to your comment, but still i face issue having  two navigation bars one with arrow and one with my Title View.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Shell in your Xamarin.Forms app than you will have to use `<Shell.TitleView>` instead of `<NavigationPage.TitleView>`. Below code worked for me...

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="QR Code" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Margin="0,0,10,0" Padding="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="20"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Comment: It should be used inside the ContentPage. And there is a few bugs about binding, hot reload etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set Navigation with MainPage like

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PageName());
```